# Visual studio 2015 RC insallation fatal error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm facing below issue when I trying to install Visual Studio 2015 RC to my windows 10 OS(Insider preview, Evaluation copy 10130)[image]

Comment: open the log files to see more details.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, VS2015 is already in RTM and Windows 10 has been out for a couple of months now. Have you tried upgrading to the current version of Windows 10 and the latest version of VS2015?

Hope that helps you get around any installation issues.

I have the latest VS2015 on multiple machines running on Windows 10, without any installation issues at the moment. (I did have installation errors in some pre-release versions earlier this year)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem. Solved by "Run as Administrator" :)